# How to find out why Outlook 2013 crash

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto

I've developed a `c# Outlook 2013 VSTO Addin` and on most of the clients the AddIn is working just fine.

On some clients my Addin causes outlook to crash.
The crazy thing is outlook only crashes from time to time.

How can I find out why Outlook crashes?

Are there tools?

I already use the environment variables 
`VSTO_SUPPRESSDISPLAYALERTS` and `VSTO_LOGALERTS`
but with now success.

Answer (score 0):

Follow [THIS](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2632425) Microsoft support article. - It clearly explains how to troubleshoot crashes and problems using the Outlook Stability Diagnostic Tool.